# Tomcat локальный и удалённый. Разная обработка регулярных ввыражений

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения, intellij-idea, tomcat

Есть такой код загрузки данных:

```
private String addAlphaTagsV2(AlphaExtract alphaExtract,
                            List<AlphaCorrectTags> alphaCorrectTagsList,
                            Set<String> newTagsList){
    String ok = "";

    /* Проходим по всем тэгам из справочника */
    for (AlphaCorrectTags correctTags : alphaCorrectTagsList) {

        Pattern pInn;
        Pattern pAccount;
        Matcher mInn;
        Matcher mAccount;

        if(correctTags.getDocNumber() != null && correctTags.getDateOper() != null){
            if(correctTags.getDocNumber().equals(alphaExtract.getDocNumber()) &&
                    correctTags.getDateOper().getTime() == alphaExtract.getDateOper().getTime() &&
                            ((correctTags.getDebetOrCredit().getVal().equals("Дебет") &&
                            alphaExtract.getDebet() > 0) ||
                                    (correctTags.getDebetOrCredit().getVal().equals("Кредит") &&
                                            alphaExtract.getCredit() > 0))) {
                if (supportingAlphaTags(alphaExtract.getPurposePayment(), correctTags.getDescription(), "no")) {
                    alphaExtract.setTags(correctTags);
                }
            }
        }else

        /* Если корректный тэг содержит ИНН или счёт, то обязательно должно быть совпадение */
        if((correctTags.getInn() != null && correctTags.getInn().length() > 0) ||
                (correctTags.getAccount() != null) && correctTags.getAccount().length() > 0){

            pInn = Pattern.compile(correctTags.getInn());
            mInn = pInn.matcher(alphaExtract.getInn());
            pAccount = Pattern.compile(correctTags.getAccount());
            mAccount = pAccount.matcher(alphaExtract.getAccount());

            if (mInn.find() && mAccount.find()) {
                if (supportingAlphaTags(alphaExtract.getPurposePayment(), correctTags.getDescription(),
                        "yes")) {
                    alphaExtract.setTags(correctTags);
                    //return ok;
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(supportingAlphaTags(alphaExtract.getPurposePayment(), correctTags.getDescription(), "no")){
                alphaExtract.setTags(correctTags);
            }
        }
    }

    if(alphaExtract.getTags() == null) {
        newTagsList.add(alphaExtract.getPurposePayment());
    }
    return ok;
}

private boolean supportingAlphaTags(String description, String corrDescr, String have) {
    String ptrn = ".*?";
    String descToPtrn;
    Pattern pDescription;
    Matcher mDescription;
    /*
        Если в описании есть знак "+", тогда разбиваем на массив,
        каждый элемент которого должен быть найден.
    */

    if (corrDescr.contains("+")) {
        boolean finds = false;
        boolean totalFinds = false;
        int cntCircle = 0;

        String[] descrSplit = corrDescr.split("\\+");
        for (String descr : descrSplit) {
            cntCircle++;
            String[] firstPatterns = descr.split(";");
            if (firstPatterns.length > 1) {
                for (String fPattr : firstPatterns) {
                    Pattern fPtrns = Pattern.compile(ptrn + fPattr.trim().toLowerCase()
                            .replaceAll("[()&$]", "")
                            + ptrn);
                    Matcher fMatchPtrns = fPtrns.matcher(description.trim().toLowerCase());
                    if(cntCircle == 1){
                        if (fMatchPtrns.find()){
                            finds = true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        if (fMatchPtrns.find() && finds && cntCircle > 1){
                            totalFinds = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Pattern fPtrn = Pattern.compile(ptrn + descr.trim().toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("[()&$]", "") + ptrn);
                Matcher fMatcher = fPtrn.matcher(description.trim().toLowerCase());
                if(cntCircle == 1){
                    if (fMatcher.find()) {
                        finds = true;
                    }
                }else {
                    if (fMatcher.find() && finds && cntCircle > 1) {
                        totalFinds = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return totalFinds;
        /*
            Если в описании НЕТ знака "+" и описание пустое
        */

    } else if (corrDescr.trim().length() == 0) {
        return have.contains("no");

    /*
        Если в описании НЕТ знака "+", тогда ищем любое совпадение
    */
    } else {
        for (String fStr : pattern.split(
                corrDescr)) {
            descToPtrn = ptrn + fStr.trim().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[()&$]", "")
                    + ptrn;
            pDescription = Pattern.compile(descToPtrn);
            mDescription = pDescription.matcher(description.
                    trim().toLowerCase());

            if (mDescription.find()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Работаю в IDEA 2017. Если развернуть приложение из IDE на локальный tomcat с подключением к удалённой базе MySQL, то всё грузится как задумано. Если же я разверну приложение на хостинге и пытаюсь загрузить, то часть строк не встаёт корректно. На локальном ПК использую Tomcat 8.5.9 и MySQL на OpenServer 5.2.2. На хостинге tomcat 7.0.70 и MySQL 5.7.14. Предполагаю, что дело как раз в tomcat, но не понимаю где и что искать. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно изучив результаты я понял, что не корректно грузятся даты. В исходный код нужно было добавить `locale`, т.к. месяцы в выгрузке написаны по-русски, а удалённый tomcat пытается распарсить в американскую кодировку. Проблема оказалась на уровень выше той функции, которую я привёл. Достаточно было добавить

```
private final Locale RU = new Locale("ru", "RU");
SimpleDateFormat monthFormatSlash = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", RU);
```

и проблема решилась.